# What assessments would you recommend prior to working out?

Tags: training

What assessments would you recommend taking prior to you (or someone you workout with) takes prior to working out? NASM recommends a [PAR-Q](http://www.nasm.org/uploadedFiles/NASMORG/objects/downloads/NASM_PAR-Q%20%28PDF,%2021k%29.pdf?n=8236), performing an overhead squat, push up and step tests...what tests have you taken and/or recommend so a person knows they're in good enough condition and have a good idea what areas to work on (strength, flexibility

Comment: Interesting, I assume you mean prior to beginning a new program (as opposed to prior to a regular workout)? I like this, quantifying that ubiquitous-but-unhelpful disclaimer to see a doctor before beginning any exercise regimen...

Comment: Before beginning a new program or maybe determining if it's time to begin/modify one

Comment: related: [Fitness tests, is there a consensus on which to use](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/24250/fitness-tests-is-there-a-consensus-on-which-to-use)

Answer (score 1):

From my personal experience, I'd say the following six tests do a pretty reasonable job at assessing a person's fitness. (I know I've had to do more flexibility assessments than just the sit and reach, but nothing is coming to mind at the moment; I'll edit this later if I recall any).

- Overhead Press
- Squats
- Push Ups
- Sit Ups
- Step Test
- Sit and Reach

Additionally, I think it also pays off to arm yourself with as much data as you can before you start a program. This gives you a meaningful way to measure and gauge your progress throughout the program.

- VO2 Max
- Body Fat Percentage
- Body Measurements (waist, neck, hip, etc.)
- Body Weight