# Fitness tests, is there a consensus on which to use?

Tags: vo2max, assessment

Is there a consensus over which of the [many test batteries](http://www.pponline.co.uk/101Evaluations/pdfs/101EvaluationTests.Chapter.1.pdf) in existence (YMCA, Harvard Step, Queens Step, Kindle, Rockport, VO2max...) best assess / quantify your current level of fitness / ability, and any improvement you may make over time.

I'm aware different tests target / measure different characteristics, so any info about the prefered / common test batteries by activity type / group e.g: Sprinting, Running, Rowing, Low impact, Strength / Anaerobic, Flexibility, Swimming...  would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this for educational purposes or to determine what level to engage yourself in? If it's the latter, forget all that and *just jump into the program* **while progressing at your own pace.** Waiting to determine your level of fitness before starting a routine is pointless. Simply start and adjust.

Comment: More Educational / Curiosity, as I've been bleeped thought several tests, from time to time.

Comment: It may depend on the activity.  For instance, rowing typically uses VO2max.

Comment: @rrirower thanks, but wondering if there's an agreed mapping of test(s) to activities, so Rowing = VO2max,  low impact= Rockport,  Cycling = xxxx, Running = yyyy, YMCA = general fitness.... ?

Comment: I think you need to specify which exercises cover X in this case.

Comment: related: [How can I measure my fitness at home without any instruments?](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/11707/how-can-i-measure-my-fitness-at-home-without-any-instruments?rq=1)